# Scala: Two classes with identical implementation

Tags: java, scala, refactoring

I came across some code written in Scala that has the following structure

```
// a.scala
object A {
    def apply(arg: String) = {
         new A(arg)
    }
    // declare a bunch of constants
    val SOME_CONSTANT_A = "some_constant_a"
}

class A {
   // define functions that use SOME_CONSTANT_A and the other constants.
}
```

We now have `b.scala` which is has `object B` with different constants and the exact same body of `class A` duplicated as `class B`(`class B` uses the constants inside `object B`).

What is the best way to refactor this code? I'd like to just have a single class, and have its behavior change based on the object somehow.

Comment: Why not just parameterize those constants?

Comment: What about something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/uoCAFZuRQ1eER7i0W9PgaQ/2)? - Althought, I probably just make a normal class that receives a config object that holds all the constants.

Answer (score 0):

Definition:

```scala
class Base(private val constant: String) {
  def printConstant(): Unit = println(constant)
}

class A extends Base("constant_for_a")
class B extends Base("constant_for_b")
```

Usage:

```scala
val a1 = new A()
a1.printConstant()
// constant_for_a

val b1 = new B()
b1.printConstant()
// constant_for_b
```